# Continuous voice recognition on Android

Tags: android, voice

I've implemented a relatively simple test application for a customer who owns a container repair facility. His aim is to deliver to his operators a tool with (possibly) voice interaction. The app basicly works well, using Google's Speech API. The annoying problem are the notification sounds when you launch the recognition intent and the subsequent timeout notification if the user doesn't speak within 4 seconds. I'm intercepting all the errors, so I can relaunch the recognizer, but it's not so comfortable hearing this couple of notification every 4 seconds, especially when you're awaiting the next container to check. A partial workaround could be the implementation of a sound trigger like the "Ok Google" feature found, for example, on my Samsung S6, but I'm not able to find info about that. The app is written with Xamarin, but it has been already ported under Android Studio in order to test the Nuance library, so if there isn't a chance for implementing "Ok Google" trigger under Xamarin, also any java suggestion would be very welcome. Obviously I don't need "Ok Google" but anoter trigger, like "inizio" or "start check", that is a user-defined trigger (or set of triggers).
Thanks.
Rodolfo